# CS6 Unable to Import MP3

Tags: flash, itunes

I am trying to import a song into my flash video. I am using CS6. I purchased the song from itunes then converted it to a MP3 within itunes. Every time I try to add the file I receive a message saying 'Couldn't Import [file path]'. I've tried two other songs (also purchased from itunes) and I always get this message. I tried another mp3 that I've had on my computer for a long time and that worked fine. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: try another encoder (for example Cdex, free) to re-encode your MP3 files and try again (parameters: 128kbps , 44100hz).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug which you need update your Quicktime & itunes,I think it will solve your problem.

here is more advice about it: [Unable to Import MP3 Files in Flash CS6](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1006009)